# vue-cli 3 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' error

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-cli-3

I am converting an existing Vue project to vue-cli 3 and have run into an unexpected problem:
In a .js file, I get this error (when I run `npm run serve`) for the line `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

> error: 'bootstrap' should be listed in the project's dependencies.
>   Run 'npm i -S bootstrap' to add it (import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
>   at src\main.js:19:1:

Which I don't understand, because my `package.json` already has bootstrap:

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper": "^1.0.1",
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vuex": "^3.0.1"
```

},

The [vue-cli doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules) mentions using a tilde to mean "import from a node module", so I also tried

```
import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

-- and got the same error.

Comment: Your import looks fine. What else do you do in the `main.js` file?

Comment: In my previous setup (before trying to switch to vue-cli 3), my webpack config listed "main.js" as my application "entry:".

Comment: I wanted to answer Bennett's question by inserting the top lines of main.js here, but StackOverflow won't let me.... grrr. 

In summary, main.js imports a bunch of stuff: Vue, Vuex, VueRouter, and a half-dozen Vue components. It defines the Vuex store.  And it does "new Vue()" to replace the "app" element (in index.html) with the router and to specify the store.

Comment: Did you try to delete the whole `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, that did solve the problem.  Thanks!  (And it's strange, because I previously did "npm install" and checked that that file existed.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by deleting node_modules and running "npm install" again.